# NodeJs, Mongoose find and populate works but aggregate, match and lookup doesn't

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am having trouble with my aggregation.. I need to return the list of the items which have the same owner's id. Owner's ID I pass as a query param.. I have tried already $match without the $in,

I tried transforming my id to mongoose.Types.ObjectId (with this I event get an error). But yet I accomlpished only empty object as return..

```
exports.getContainersByOwner = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const { id }: any = req.query;

  try {
    const containers = await Container.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "containerstypes",
          localField: "containerTypeID",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "containerTypes",
        },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "owners",
          localField: "ownerId",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "owner",
        },
      },
      { $unwind: "$containerTypes" },
      { $unwind: "$owner" },
      { $match: { "owner._id": { $in: [id] } } },
    ]);
    res.status(200).json(containers);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).json({ success: false, msg: "Container not found" });
  }
};
```

If I remove line $match from my code api returns all the items which is OK, but I need to achieve that the returned items have the same id... I need to match the colored id (owner._id)
[image]

The Container's model is:

```
const ContainerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ownerId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Owners", required: true },
  manufacturingNo: { type: String, required: true },
  IdentificationNo: { type: String, required: true },
  manufacturingDate: { type: Date, required: true },
  nextInspectionDate: { type: Date, required: true },
  certificateNo: { type: String, required: false },
  containerTypeID: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "ContainersType",
    required: true,
  },
});
```

---

if I use this approach it works, but object structure is not right, so in frontend there is much more changes to do.. This is not possible at the moment

```
  try {
    const containers = await Container.find({
      ownerId: id,
    })
      .populate("containerTypeID")
      .populate("ownerId");
    res.status(200).json(containers);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).json({ success: false, msg: "Container not found" });
  }
```

Comment: is `id` a list of ids or a single id?

Comment: It is list of IDs

Comment: Added the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$match` is logically wrong:

```
 { $match: { "owner._id": { $in: [id] } } }
```

Since `id`, itself is a list of Ids, your $in becomes list of lists ([[]]). Try simply this:

```
 { $match: { "owner._id": { $in: id } } }
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! :D Can you please look also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73468002/nodejs-mongoose-if-id-exists-do-nothing-if-doesnt-exist-push-the-new-one-to-t

Comment: Can you mention the order of the execution of these stages?

Comment: They get executed in the order they are written, first the lookups, then unwind, and finally  match