# NodeJS, Mongoose if ID exists do nothing, if doesn't exist push the new one to the array

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have User model and every user can have an array of ownerId's. I want to make an API which will push a new ownerId to the array, but if this ownerId already exists, do nothing..

I have tried $addToSet but it doesn't work..
However it works with $push, but if ownerId already exists it keeps pushing the same ownerId so i have duplicates which is not OK..

User model

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String, required: true, min: 6, max: 255 },
  password: { type: String, required: true, min: 4, max: 1024 },
  role: { type: String, required: true, default: "User" },
  owners: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Owners",
      required: false,
    },
  ],
});
```

And my NodeJS Mongoose API:

```
exports.addOwnerToUser = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    let ObjectID = require("mongodb").ObjectID;

    const user = {
      email: req.body.email,
      ownerId: req.body.ownerId,
    };
    const updatedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: req.params.userId },
      {
        $push: { owners: req.body.ownerId },
      }
    );
    console.log(updatedUser);

    res.status(201).json({ sucess: true, msg: "User updated sucessfully" });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).json(err);
  }
};
```

Thanks

Comment: Your schema defines `ownerId` as an array of objects, something like this `{ownerId:{ownerId: "111"}}`, is it expected?

Answer (score 0):

$push will just push data in array, in your case you should use $addToSet

$addToSet only ensures that there are no duplicate items added to the set and does not affect existing duplicate elements.

```
 const updatedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate({
    { _id: req.params.userId },
    'ownerId.ownerId': {
       '$ne': new mongoose.ObjectID(req.body.ownerId)
    }
   }, {
     $addToSet: {
        'ownerId.ownerId': new mongoose.ObjectID(req.body.ownerId)
     }
   }, {
     new: true
   });
```

Comment: Hm, it returns me empty object, some error is in the query. https://imgur.com/FsN7GlJ

Comment: `const updatedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate({
    _id: req.params.userId,
    'ownerId.ownerId': {
       '$ne': new mongoose.ObjectID(req.body.ownerId)
    }
   }, {
     $addToSet: {
        'ownerId.ownerId': new mongoose.ObjectID(req.body.ownerId)
     }
   }, {
     new: true
   });` Try this I updated the query.

Comment: It doesn't  add new ownerId to the array. In console.log uspdatedUser is "null" https://imgur.com/a/VEmXq2z

Answer (score 0):

just remove below query

```
'ownerId.ownerId': {
       '$ne': req.body.ownerId
    }
```

Updated code.

```
const updatedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate({
    _id: req.params.userId,
   }, {
     $addToSet: {
        'ownerId.ownerId': req.body.ownerId
     }
   }, {
     new: true
   });
```

**OR**

with ownerId Query

```
const updatedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate({
    _id: req.params.userId,
    'ownerId.ownerId': {
           '$ne': req.body.ownerId
        }
   }, {
     $push: {
        'ownerId': {ownerId: req.body.ownerId }
     }
   }, {
     new: true
   });
```

Comment: Problem with push is that if this id already exists, it duplicates it.. $addToSet just doesn't work sadly I don't know why

Comment: with $push you have to apply this Query with _id,  `'ownerId.ownerId': {
           '$ne': new mongoose.ObjectID(req.body.ownerId)
        }` then it won't be duplicate.

Comment: Look at the error: code: https://imgur.com/a/KLar6su
response: https://imgur.com/a/h2UVZKn

Comment: Your code is wrong in the code image.

`const updatedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate({
    _id: req.params.userId,
    'ownerId.ownerId': {
           '$ne': new mongoose.ObjectID(req.body.ownerId)
        }
   }, {
     $push: {
        'ownerId': {ownerId:new mongoose.ObjectID(req.body.ownerId)}
     }
   }, {
     new: true
   });` update by this.

Comment: It doesn't update base.. my updatedUser is null: https://imgur.com/GKVRxlZ

Comment: Try the above updated code this should work. 
i have removed to making an instance of ObjectId

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247503/discussion-between-devz-and-shubham-jasani).

Answer (score 0):

Your schema design is not right, that is why $addToSet is not working for you.

so, if you want multiple owners in the user object please change your schema design to this

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String, required: true, min: 6, max: 255 },
  password: { type: String, required: true, min: 4, max: 1024 },
  role: { type: String, required: true, default: "User" },
  owners: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Owners",
        required: false,
     }],
});
```

After this use $addToSet to add the new owner id in the user object

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
   { _id: req.params.userId },
   { $addToSet: { owners: req.body.ownerId } }
 )
```

it will not add the duplicates
For Reference: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/

Note:
As per my previous experience with this kind of work, it is better if you change the key `ownerId` to `owners`
because in general these are the owners array not the ownerId

Comment: okey, can you please also post content of await User.findOneAndUpdate( { ...... } ) function?

Comment: @devZ I updated the User.findOneAndUpdate too

Comment: I am sorry but it eodn't solve the problem. sadly

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
exports.addOwnerToUser = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    try {
        let ObjectID = require("mongodb").ObjectID;

        const user = {
            email: req.body.email,
            ownerId: req.body.ownerId,
        };
        const updatedUser = await User.findOne({
                _id: req.params.userId
            })
            .then(user => {
                if (user.ownerId[0]) {
                    user.ownerId[0].ownerId = req.body.ownerId;
                }
            })
        console.log(updatedUser);

        res.status(201).json({
            sucess: true,
            msg: "User updated sucessfully"
        });
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(404).json(err);
    }
};
```